# is there a way to declare a group of members with the same accessor in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, accessor

i have this basic question : is there a way to declare a group of members with the same accessor in c#?, something like "accessor:" of c++ that specify that from that line downward every member have this accessor

Edit:
with "accessor" i mean access-specifier like public, private, protected, etc.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *accessor*. Can you give an example?

Comment: @ Space_C0wb0y: I think he meant *access-specifiers*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant access-specifiers. If so, then no. You cannot do that in C#, like you do in C++.

However, if it's `private`, then you can omit it altogether, because by default, everything (fields, properties, methods) in C# is `private`.

Comment: :(, i really like those access-specifiers and don't like to see those public keywords everywhere

Answer (score 0):

No. C# does not have this feature.

However, if you Alt-Shift-Drag in Visual Studio 2010, you can type it all at once.

See this video: http://scottcate.com/tricks/503/

Comment: Are you recommending a block selection? If so, then typing "private" will just prefix *every line* with "private", not just the declarations.